# Can we generate energy with the pseudo-forces in a non-inertia frame (energy without a physical interaction)?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy

Wikipedia says pseudo forces can considered to do work, if so can energy be generated by them and what will the source of such a energy without a physical interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Pseudo forces can do work. In noninertial system, you can SEE the work, and in inertial you can't SEE anything due to Pseudo forces vanish. Energy is  conserved forever. In noninertial system, the work of Pseudo forces just comes from the noninertial system itself. If you consider object and noninertial system together, the object can't obtain or lose anything, so does the work.

Answer (score 0):

One example: a free particle at rest in an inertial system. There are no forces, no energy, no change in motion, no work. The same particle seen from an accelerated reference frame: pseudo force, increasing energy, change in motion, pseudo work. Thus yes, the pseudo force can do work on its reference system, and a free particle would gain energy. But this energy does not have to transfer across reference systems. In the inertial system the energy remained at zero all the time.

Comment: my problem more so with causality  then with energy, in a non inertial causality is adaptive we have generated a force out of a nowhere and it does work out a nowhere, what is the source of this energy this work out of no where will result in a perpetual system with no input of energy , that is what I think

Comment: Energy is not conserved, but causality is not affected (but it depends of what you exactly mean by causality).

Comment: pseudo forces doesn't pain my brain because for me it is just a method of satisfying law of inertia in non inertia system. but energy demands a source and if not the fundamental interaction of standard model what the cause of such of energy arising for pseudo force?